# Razor model binding not sending all elements through

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model that has 2 lists of models. I get the same issue with both lists so I will explain just one of them (I am doing the same steps for each of the lists).

One list is for the customer, it is made up of a number of fields (supplied via an api on a thirdparty system I am talking to, it needs to be dynamic as the thirdparty can send other things through)

For example, for the customer the fields are:
`title`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `address`, `state`, `dob`, `gender`.

On these fields there are a number of properties that aid in if they should be displayed or not. In my case we are using, `title`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `dob`, `gender`

When I submit the form the values for title, `firstname` and `lastname` come through in the model fine. However the values for `dob` and `gender` do not. They appear in the form collection, but not mapped to the list in the model in the function.

Here is an example of how the elements are added to the page

(if go through them in a for loop, checking if they should be used on the page and if so I see what type of field they are (text, dropdown, date etc) and I then add it to the page)

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].value, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Model.CustomerFields[i].description, style = (Model.CustomerFields[i].visible ? "" : "display: none;") });
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].code)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].description)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].type)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].readOnly)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].visible)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].lookupGroup)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].customGroup)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.CustomerFields[i].sequence)
```

It seems that as I am breaking the sequence of the list of fields it does not pass them through.

I have been looking around and googling and cannot find anything that would explain what is going on. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I updated the code to add the remaining fields (the ones not needed on the page) as hidden elements, add all the fields come through to the post form function as expected. Does anyone know the reason it will not work with out doing this?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on based on what you given. Can you share viewmodels + the keys of the form collection?

Comment: its fine it is working once i added all fields (within hidden elements, if they were not required). It is a little POC so not investing a mass of time into it. Cheers